# ios swift how to set a save button in the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

I have a `MainViewController` which is a table view controller, with custom cells where the user can select some data. There is a button on this `MainViewController` that goes to `PreferencesViewController`, which has two buttons on the navigation bar, one for back (it is wokring now good), and the other one for `save` (here is my problem)

This is a screenshot of the navitation bar in the `PreferencesViewController`:
[image]

I drag a segue from the `save` bar button back to the `MainViewController`.

#### my problem

when I hit save, the `MainViewController` appears, but without saving the values the the user has already selected. sounds like a new instance of this `MainViewContoller` is being created.

What am i missing here? what other approach i should have already used please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution myself using:

1- custom delegate:

2- self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect your save button to an IBAction, not a segue.

In that IBAction, do whatever you need to do to save your data, and then do a dismissViewController:animated: call yourself in code.

If you wanted to use a segue you wouldn't be able to (easily) save your data, and yes, it creates a new instance.

An alternative would be to connect your save button to an unwind segue, rolls back, or unwinds, one or more segues to get back to a previous view controller. To do that you'd have to put your save logic in prepareForSegue (with code to test which segue is being invoked and only save in response to the save segue.)

Comment: the alternative way u suggested sounds hard to me. is it good just to connect my save bar item to an outlet and do this dismissViewontroller?

Comment: Connect your save bar item to an `IBAction` you mean? Sure, that's easy and fine.

Comment: and please in order to pass these data back to `MainViewController`, what do i have to do ?

Comment: wait please, your dismissViewController , didn't work, it throw me back to the **first** view controlelr that was connetec to the navigation controller, while I want to go back to the `MainViewController`, why? I guess I shuld give u more context then. i have two navigatino controllers, one for the a view controller that has a button, and when clicked i got to compltely another navitation controller. did you get me please or i post a video to u ?

Comment: `        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)` this is the function that i used

Comment: hello, did you leave please ?